# What happens if I delete dump.txt file in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

After finishing my project, I found that there is a huge (55 MB) `dump.txt` file inside `app\build\outputs\mapping\release` in android studio project. I googled and found that this is from ProGuard.

Now, my question is if I delete that file, will there be any problem? It's making my whole project size greater than 100 MB

Comment: Why don't you copy the file into another folder, then remove the original one and see if any problems? If so, put the copy back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dump.txt` is a file created by ProGuard. As stated on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html):

> describes the internal structure of all the class files in the .apk
>   file

You can safely delete the file, the important thing to remember is to save in a safe place `mapping.txt` as it is necessary to debug the obfuscated APK. See [Decoding Obfuscated Stack Traces](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding) for more information.

Comment: Note: since Android Gradle Plugin 3.2, you explicitly have to ask for generation.